# Zeiss VR one screen phone brightness dimming

Tags: java, android, screen-brightness, vrone

I just want to know how the screen parameters (especially brightness) of the used phone are taken into account in the Zeiss VR One headset. Does the parameters of the phone are overwritten by some parameters from the headset?
If anybody can answer me. 
Thanks,

Jennifer

Answer (score 0):

The VR One Unity SDK sets `Screen.sleepTimeout == SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;` therefore prevents the screen from dimming while the user is wearing the device.
As far as I know, while `SleepTimeout.NeverSleep`is set, the screen's brightness is maximum.